# How to remove multiple Dataframe header suffices that start with \?

Tags: python

I have a Dataframe `data`, whose headers contain multiple different suffices. The common feature among all headers is that the suffix begins with ;

```
Column-A\foo    Column-B\bar
some data       some data
```

I'm trying to get the output to look like;

```
Column-A        Column-B
some data       some data
```

I have tried;

```
data.columns = data.columns.str.replace(r'\$', '')
```

But this does not work.

Is there a nice way to do this or should I specify the full name of each suffix?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your regex for finding a backslash and trailing characters isn't correct.

```
import pandas

data = pandas.DataFrame(columns=[r'Column-A\foo',r'Column-B\bar'])
data.columns = data.columns.str.replace(r'\\.*', '', regex=True)

print(data)
```

Output:

```
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [Column-A, Column-B]
Index: []
```

Answer (score 3):

I believe you need to escape `"\"`. Hence, `Column-A\foo` should be written as `Column-A\\foo`.

Hence you may do this:

```
data.columns = data.columns.str.split('\\').str.get(0)
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
import pandas as pd

#Split the column headers at '\' and take the first part
data.columns = data.columns.str.split('\\', expand=True)[0]

print(data)
```

Comment: Answer needs supporting information
Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).